# ByteBuffer.allocate within Constructors

Tags: java, constructor, bytebuffer

In my code I have a class with a ByteBuffer and two Constructors. Depending on the constructor, I want to allocate a different about of space to the ByteBuffer.

```
ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);

1st_constructor(arg1, arg2, arg3){
     data = ByteBuffer.allocate(5);   
}

1st_constructor(arg1, arg2){
    data = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);    
}
```

I was wondering, is this the correct way to do this? I only declared the ByteBuffer outside the constructors because I thought this is the only way the instantiated object would be able to access it (not sure if that is right though?)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you can ensure that all of your constructors would create a ByteBuffer, then there is no reason to pre-create it before the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
final ByteBuffer data;

1st_constructor(arg1, arg2, arg3){
     data = ByteBuffer.allocate(5);   
}

1st_constructor(arg1, arg2){
    data = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have

```
ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
```

Either mark it as final as above, or move it into a separate default constructor if that's your intention.